# Import variable from .env - Express Cloud function - shows undefined

Tags: express, environment-variables

.env

```
AES_SECRET= 123
```

index.ts

```
dotenv.config();
const secret = process.env.AES_SECRET;
.
.
const decrypt = (hash: string) => {
 var reb64 = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(hash);
  var bytes = reb64.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
  var decrypt = AES.decrypt(bytes, secret);
  var plainText = decrypt.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

  return plainText
}
```

Error - Object is possibly 'undefined'.
secret shows as undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try it like this:

```js
dotenv.config();
const secret = <string>process.env.AES_SECRET;
.
.
const decrypt = (hash: string) => {
 var reb64 = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(hash);
  var bytes = reb64.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
  var decrypt;
  
  if (secret !== undefined) {
     decrypt = AES.decrypt(bytes, secret);
  }
  
  var plainText = decrypt.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

  return plainText
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated:
I ended up doing this

```
const presecret = process.env.AES_SECRET;
const secret = presecret!.toString();
```